# VBA Outlook keep formatting of email with replacement

Tags: vba, replace, outlook

I am currently working with Excel and Outlook VBA and I got the problem that when using the Replace function to change the mail body the formatting (font size, bold font, hyperlinks) gets deleted. That destroys the readablity of the mail and I need to change this issue.

```
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(Path) 

    With OutMail
    .To = Receiver(ActiveCell.Offset(, 11)) 'receiver is a sub-function that removes Umlauts
    .Subject = "End of contract" & ActiveCell.Value & " " & _
     ActiveCell.Offset(, 3).Value & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(, 2).Value & " - " & ActiveCell.Offset(, 6).Value
    '        .Body = Replace(OutMail.Body, "FIRST NAME; NAME", ActiveCell.Offset(, 11).Value)   'Error -> code changes all formatting
    .FlagRequest = "Follow up"
    .FlagDueBy = ReminderDate
     End With
```

I heard that the replacement function is the solution for my problem, but it seems like the replacement function is used differently and I didn't manage to make it work in my code. Can anyone help me out with these?

Best,

Benjamin

Comment: Try to change `.Body` to `.HTMLBody` in both places.

Comment: Hi @KazimierzJawor thanks for your comment. I tried it, but it did not make it better. With .htmlbody not only the formatting vanishes but also the paragraphs.

Comment: try to `Debug.Print OutMail.HTMLBody` and `debug.Print Activecell.offset(,11)` to see what you have and what you are trying to replace to.

Comment: I just posted a piece of my code. My macro automatically opens the mail object afterwards. That is not the problem. The text and everything was already okay. The only problem is that the formatting changes when using .htmlbody.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution but you could try to diverse the email.body creation. First change the value and then add formating.

Comment: I am opening an Outlook object so the formatting has already be done before and is not applied by VBA. I want to use the template that already has been created and just change 4 words.